# Disable Drag (not drop) in the Windows Explorer Navigation Pane

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, drag-and-drop

I find myself occasionally grabbing some random folder and dropping it into some other random folder in the Windows Explorer navigation pane (the left hand pane with the folder list).

The really big problem is that I am sometimes unaware that I did it, and even if I do realize, I've no idea what folder went where (thankfully, if I am aware I can CTRL-Z and undo the move).

Is there any way to either disable dragging only, of if that's not possible, dragging and dropping in that pane?

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution to this? I basically have [the same issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1657921/move-confirmation-dialog-in-file-explorer?noredirect=1&lq=1) (although I'm on Windows 10) and the current answer here didn't help me for the same reasons it didn't help you.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that is possible to disable drag functionality for this pane. However, to avoid accidental drag and drop, you can adjust the drag sensitivity so that it takes a greater effort to trigger a drag and drop operation. By default, the mouse needs to travel four pixels with the button held down for a drag operation to be initiated. To make it harder to initiate an accidental drag operation, just crank this number higher.

## How to change drag sensitivity:

**Warning**: Always back up the resistry before making any changes. To do this, in the registry editor, select File/Export. In the Export Range options, select All. Save the file to the Desktop. If something goes wrong, you can right click that file to restore the registry.

### Option 1

1. Press the Windows Logo Key+R to bring up the Run dialog.
2. Type regedit.exe in the Open box and click OK.
3. Navigate to the following key: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`
4. In the right side pane, look for the following: `DragHeight`  and `DragWidth`.
5. Right click each one of these values and select Modify.
6. In the Value Data box, type `100` and click OK.
7. Log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

### Option 2

1. Press the Windows Logo Key+R to bring up the Run dialog.
2. Type cmd.exe in the Open box and click OK.
3. Type: `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DragHeight /d 100 /f`
4. Type: `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v DragWidth /d 100 /f`
5. Log out and log back in for the changes to take effect.

**Remarks**

- Both options will set the sensitivity to 100 pixels of movement. Adjust as required.
- The default value for `DragHeight` and `DragWidth` is `4`.

**Sources**

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/04/10/9541813.aspx
- https://kb.cadzow.com.au:444/cadzow/details.aspx?ID=2391

Comment: In my case this idea is not useful - the accidental drag/drop happens as I move my mouse rapidly up or down the long list. It's **always** more than any threshold value that you could set, usually a good percentage of my 1920x1600 pixel monitor.

Comment: The bigger problem with this solutiion is that the threshold applies to ALL attempts to drag an item at desktop level. Including: dragging title bar of a window to change its location on screen, dragging from windows explorer or desktop into some application window (e.g. to drop a file onto Skype or other messaging app). Very regrettable that Windows still has no way to limit Windows Explorer accidental drags only.

Comment: .. also affects "dragging" the separator between columns in windows explorer, details view. E.g. if want to make "Name" column wider. Have to drag the column separator by number of pixels set in DragWidth.

Comment: To avoid needing to log out and back in, use a PowerShell script to call the relevant API instead of editing the registry directly.
https://gist.github.com/jstangroome/eec58484f8060b44ecc23d383ad22d94

Comment: Here's a little system tray app that will let you adjust these settings immediately: [DragOptions](https://lesferch.github.io/DragOptions/)