# "Move" confirmation dialog in File Explorer?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, file-management, accessibility, recovery

Windows 10.

I have Tourette's and occasionally when moving the mouse I'll click it. Every once in a while I get unlucky and have a File Explorer window open and accidentally drag some random folder to some random place.

The only way I can really tell that this happens is I'll see the item list lose an item out of a corner of my eye, then think, "argh, not again" (I don't even want to think about how many times I didn't notice at all). Then I have to kind of hunt around to find out what I did so I can fix it, because for some reason the explorer "undo" doesn't catch moves all the time (especially when they happen in the folder pane on the left).

So my question is: Is there some way to enable a folder move confirmation dialog in Explorer? (Or if not is there some way to make the Undo feature have better coverage?) (Or maybe make it so I have to shift+drag to move or something?)

I use TeraCopy as my copy handler but afaict there's no move confirmation feature. I'm not against registry hacks or installing 3rd party software if needed, although I'd prefer not to.

To me it's an accessibility issue. I did check through the accessibility settings but I couldn't find anything helpful. I checked both the Win 10 settings and the old school Control Panel -> Ease of Access settings.

I read through [Disable Drag (not drop) in the Windows Explorer Navigation Pane](https://superuser.com/questions/713003/disable-drag-not-drop-in-the-windows-explorer-navigation-pane) (thanks for the link), but the solution there isn't quite what I'm looking for, for similar reasons to why it wasn't the right solution for the OP there: My accidental drags almost always are past the threshold, and also that applies to *all* drag operations, which isn't really ideal.

Comment: I suggest you go through the Windows 10 Accessibility settings and look here rather than trying to change Windows on your own.

Comment: @John  I did but I couldn't find anything. I had *thought* I remembered some sort of mouse click time threshold thing for twitchy people, which wouldn't be ideal but would definitely help, but I couldn't find that, either. I might have misremembered, too.

Comment: In Mouse Settings (Control Panel) you can control the length of time that represents a double click. That may help.

Comment: @John Thanks! Incidentally, that actually might be helpful for other issues I have. Unfortunately, the folder move problem is a single-click drag issue. :/

Comment: @harrymc 
I read through https://superuser.com/questions/713003/disable-drag-not-drop-in-the-windows-explorer-navigation-pane (thanks for the link), but the solution there isn't quite what I'm looking for, for similar reasons to why it wasn't the right solution for the OP there: My accidental drags almost always are past the threshold (due to rapid movement speed), and also that applies to *all* drag operations, which isn't really ideal.

Comment: (Also that was Windows 7)

Comment: The registry hasn't changed since Windows 7, but I have reopened the post.

Comment: You may be able to engage Mouse Click and Lock .  On the right, click on the Advanced Mouse Settings link.
In the Mouse Properties dialog, switch to the Buttons tab. ...
Turn on (check) the option Turn on ClickLock under the appropriate section    See if that helps. I can click lock the middle button on my external Logitech mouse.

Comment: Press Ctrl+Z for undo when this happens.

Comment: @user1292580 "the explorer 'undo' doesn't catch moves all the time" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to disable drag-and-drop only in Explorer by
using the free [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following AutoHotkey script will either disable drag or convert
it into rename (same as dragging the cursor over a file-name).
It basically converts any left-mouse-down action into a complete
left-click, so no drag can be done:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_class CabinetWClass
LButton::Send, {LButton}
```

After installing AutoHotKey, put the above text in a `.ahk` file and
double-click it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on
the green H icon in the traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: This looks promising; I'm going to check it out and I'll report back. I also want to dig a little and see if I can make a drag require a modifier key; which would let me move things but not by accident. Thanks; I'll let you know if this works out.

Answer (score 1):

I use a program called "Drag Drop Confirm".  Love it.
https://github.com/broken-e/DragDropConfirm

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).